# document.getElementById().style.[style] returns blank

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the width of an object using `document.getElementById("bk").style.width`, but it always returns blank, along with any other style I use.

```js
window.onload = function sizemake() {
  console.log("There should be something after this:" +
    document.getElementById("bk").style.width)
}
```

```css
#keyboard {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  width: 1366px;
  height: 90px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#wk,
#bk {
  display: table-cell;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#wk {
  position: relative;
  height: 90px;
  width: 1.92%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#bk {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 52px;
  width: 58.05%;
  right: -9.04px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id='wk'>
  <div id='bk'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it may cause you should use `document.getElementById("bk").clientWidth` to get it, the `document.getElementById("bk").style.width = '1000px'；`  is used to set the style

Answer (score 2):

The property you are accessing is for the inline style attribute.

If you had the following markup you would get the value `100px`

```
<div id='wk'>
  <div id='bk' style="width: 100px;"></div>
</div>
```

To get the actual width of the element use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

```
document.getElementById("bk").getBoundingClientRect().width
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try jQuery

```
$("bk").width()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
document.querySelector("div.bk").style.width
```